# Creating a shortcut to a SharePoint document that lives in a different SharePoint library

Tags: 2007, document-library

I'm having trouble creating a shortcut of a document in SharePoint. The document lives on a SharePoint library, and we need the shortcut to be in a different SharePoint library.

Is this possible? All I get is "Unable to Create Shortcut" when I try to create it in different ways.

Any help would be great Thanks -V

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, here is my solution:

Go to Library you wish to place shortcut and go to List Settings.
Advanced Settings and  Allow management of content types? Yes.
Now, back in List Settings, scroll to Add from existing site content types and in there,
Add a Link to Document.

Now back in your Document Library, New will have a New Link, and you just place title and URL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Bingo! this is exactly what I was going to post.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the main functionality many people/Organizations have.
What I have done is, I am using Content query web part to display the contents of the document library.

Note: If you do not see the content query webpart, you will have to activate the sharepoint server publishing Infrastructure.

Site Actions-> Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration.

Regards
Vijay

Comment: What if I don't want the entire library though? We only need 1 document...